# "overly confident" vs "over confident"

Tags: grammaticality, adjectives, adverbs

I hear or read both phrases regularly, and they seem to have the same meaning to me. But do they have different meanings? Or is “overly confident” even grammatically correct?

Comment: You keep using the word "gramatically" in your questions. It hurts.

Comment: so what do you suppose I should use? I wanted to ask if the grammar was correct.

Comment: Mel, try to spell the word correctly.

Comment: oh sorry my bad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Confident* is an adjective and *overly* is an adverb. Adjectives are usually modified by adverbs. This is a perfectly normal and grammatical construction.

The other word is usually written as one word: *overconfident*.

The meanings are the same.